# get game game details from the server

Tags: php

i want to get game server details like current map and players from a server but couldnt figure the logic behind this.

for example:

http://www.game-monitor.com/cstrike_GameServer/212.175.66.69:27015/FeeL_The_ForCe_PrO.html

as you aware the server ip and port is 212.175.66.69:27015 in this example.

I'm using PHP!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this documentation, http://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Server_queries

As far as the PHP part, http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-create.php, should be useful to you.

Comment: Please consider marking of these responses the answer if it is.

Answer (score 1):

The thing you're looking for, in this specific case, is "rcon."  It happens that [someone has written a PHP class that can issue rcon commands](http://fremnet.net/article/199/source-rcon-class).  I can't vouch for whether it works or not, only that it exists.

Comment: Ahh, rcon. I miss my Counter-Strike days. I don't really have anything constructive to add to this.